# How to call class expressions from console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pixi.js

I'm debugging a games production code which is made with Pixi.js. In order to test some functionalities I want to call some framework functions from console. In the following code there is the minified version of the "Move" class which is called when a click on canvas is done.
This constructor is called by other class so those `e, i, s, n` arguments come from another class. When I type MyGame["Move"](arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4); this function should work. Although 3rd and 4th arguments are known, I don't know how to pass those generated e and i arguments.

```
! function (t) {
    class e {
        constructor(e, i, s, n) {
            this.gameObject = e, 
            this.options = n, 
            this.goPositionPath = i || {
                x: [],
                y: []
            }, 
            this.goPosition = s || {
                x: i[i.x.length - 1],
                y: i[i.y.length - 1]
            }, 
            this.init()
        } 
        init() {
            return __awaiter(this, undefined, undefined, function* () {
                let generatePath = yield this.generatePath();
                if (generatePath && (this.goPositionPath = generatePath), this.sendRequestToBackend(), this.options.waitBackend) return this.gameObject.currentMove = null;
                this.editPath(), this.calculatePathDistanceAndTime(), this.initAnimation()
            })
        } 
        generatePath() { /* ... */ }
        sendRequestToBackend () { /* ... */ }
        // ...
        // Other functions...
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    // Some logic
    // ...
    t.Move = e
  }(MyGame || (MyGame = {}));
  var MyGame;
```

Is there a way to call these functions from console with available game information?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the frameworks prevent you from polluting the global space by wrapping all the code inside a closure.
Best way to overcome on this while debugging is to use debugger (in your browser).

You can add e.g. a breakpoint, and when the execution is over that breakpoint, you can run your own commands in the console in the same space as the breakpoint.

Comment: Is there a way to expose those closures?

Comment: You can hack around with global variables defined outside of it and assign functions, etc to them from the closure, but it may cause build time issues if your framework has some checkers.